# Exporting to Excel Showing (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, export, c#-3.0, export-to-excel

am using `Microsoft office 2013` office professional. so when am trying to export data from `c#` to `Excel` it shows the  following error.

> ```
> The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))
> ```

but when am using the `office 2007` there is no issue with my code. only, the error occur while using `office 2013`. can any one please provide a suitable solution for this.

The following code am using

```
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objWorkSheet1 = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
                {
                    Visible = false,
                    DisplayAlerts = false,
                    ScreenUpdating = false
                };
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks objWorkbooks = objExcel.Workbooks;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objWorkbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets = objWorkbook.Worksheets;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objCells;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myCell;
                var iCurrentRow = 10;
                var dt = ds;
                int columnsCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                objWorkSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)(objSheets[1]);
                objCells = objWorkSheet1.Cells;
                objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, columnsCount - 1] = ReportCaption;
                objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, columnsCount - 1].Font.Size = 15;
                objWorkSheet1.Range[objWorkSheet1.Cells[5, 2], objWorkSheet1.Cells[5, columnsCount - 1]].Merge();
                objWorkSheet1.Cells[5, 2] = "Printed By: " + Common.Utilities.UserName; ;
                objWorkSheet1.Range[objWorkSheet1.Cells[6, 2], objWorkSheet1.Cells[6, columnsCount - 1]].Merge();
                objWorkSheet1.Cells[6, 2] = "Date: " + DateTime.Now;
                objWorkSheet1.Range[objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2], objWorkSheet1.Cells[4, columnsCount - 1]].Merge();
                if (name != null)
                    if (name.Length > 0)
                        objWorkSheet1.Cells[8, 2] = "NAME: " + name;
                objWorkSheet1.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2], (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[4, columnsCount - 1]).Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                objWorkSheet1.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[2, 2], (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objWorkSheet1.Cells[4, columnsCount - 1]).Cells.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                for (var h = 0; h < dt.Columns.Count; h++)
                {
                    myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[iCurrentRow, h + 1];
                    myCell.Value2 = dt.Columns[h].ColumnName;
                }
                iCurrentRow++;
                for (var r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
                {
                    for (var c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "String" || dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "DateTime")
                        {
                            myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[r + iCurrentRow, c + 1];
                            myCell.Value2 = "'" + dt.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[r + iCurrentRow, c + 1];
                            myCell.Value2 = dt.Rows[r][c];
                        }
                    }
                }
                objWorkSheet1.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit();
                objWorkSheet1.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                objWorkbook.SaveAs(savingFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                objWorkbook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                objExcel.Quit();
```

The following image will come when it close it will not work
                   [image]

Comment: which statement is throwing that error?

Comment: this statemnet, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
                {
                    Visible = false,
                    DisplayAlerts = false,
                    ScreenUpdating = false
                };

Comment: where is that statement in your code?

Comment: in my excel 2013 that statement works.

Comment: in that statement it shows one microsoft office activation window , if we close it will not work. but in hte debug mode it will work

Comment: you want to close an Excel instance right after instantiating it?

Comment: did not understand

Comment: you wrote _" if we close it will not work"_: what are you _closing_?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135495/discussion-between-dona-susan-issac-and-user3598756).

Comment: i have put the image of the windows shows during the export when this window is closed it will shows the above error

Comment: one more thing it is running in thread.

Comment: well it seems like you have to purchase/activate your Office license...

Comment: because if in the debug mode it will work correctly

Comment: during debug mode if this msg occur , and if i close it will work with next line, but with out debug mode it will come with previos error

Comment: in debug mode, would you succeed in completing the whole sub after the "exception"?

Comment: so whats can i do for it

Comment: Well, you could answer my last question...

Comment: No, in the debug mode only it will continue and do t he process with out any error, other wise directly comes to the catch statement with the above error

Comment: So in debug mode the whole macro completes successfully after clicking "close" button in that "Office Activation Wizard" dialog box. I wouldn't have guessed that, but since it is like that I'm clueless. I guess you already tried some `Try-Catch` block, didn't you?

Comment: s i used `try catch` in the method but in that it is not showing any thing during debug ,but when this message come it shows the error of the above message

Comment: so in debug mode the `Try-Catch` block doesn't catch any error, does it?

Comment: NO .. it doesnot catch any error

Comment: so it's not actually a run time error. you may search SO or the web for some "pop out catching" to click its "Close" button. Or you may activate the licence...

Comment: can u provide a sample code for it from my code,

Comment: I don't have any. you have to search SO or the web for it